# FileReader onload does not work in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I am working on a project where I need to show preview of image before croping.i am using jquery.Jcrop.js v0.9.12 plugin and it works great in all the browsers. but in Safari preview image does not display. I found that in lower version of Safari FileReader is not supported. i have safari 5.1.7.
here is the code :

```
 var e = {};
e.pf = window.FileReader && function (e, t, n) {
    var r = new FileReader;
    r.onload = function (n) {
        var r = new Image;
        r.onload = function (n) {
            if (!t.beforePick.call(e, r)) {
                e.setImage(r.src, t.afterPick)
            }
        };
        r.onerror = function (n) {
            t.beforePick.call(e, null)

        };
        r.src = n.target.result
    };
    r.readAsDataURL(n)
};
```

Do we have any other way to read file in lower version of Safari for window?

Thanks

Comment: Well what does `window.FileReader` return is it supported. My guess is it is no and there is nothing you can do and why are you using Safari on windows? It is 2 years old and really outdated.

Comment: thanks @epascarello for your reply. safari 5.1.7 is the latest version on windows 7. and it partially supports the filereader because it successfully enters in e.pf block but we have issue in r.onload.

Comment: And when it is in the onload what happens?

Comment: It never enters in r.onload.

Comment: So did you add a error handler.

Comment: I am not sure whether it's correct or not but i added this r.onerror = function (n) {
            alert("in error");

        }; just before r.readAsDataURL(n). but did not get this alert too.